# Sitemap.xml for all store views

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore, sitemaps

I am using several store views.
Each has different links so I would like to have a `sitemap.xml` including all links from all store views.

What is the practise of creating a proper `sitemap.xml`? Currently I can create it for one store view only ... do I combine them by hand?

Answer (score 5):

You can just generate the `sitemap.xml` per store.

In your `robots.txt` add the path to the sitemaps, for example:

```
# Sitemap
Sitemap: http://www.yourdomain.com/sitemap/de/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://www.yourdomain.com/sitemap/en/sitemap.xml
```